# Shopify If statement in CSS template file?

Tags: css, if-statement, shopify

I'm am editing a Shopify site for a client and I came across this code in the css file.

```
.pass-foot a {
  font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;

  // It's this piece I'm talking about
  **{% if settings.password_bg != "no_password_bg" %}
  color: #fff;
  {% endif %}**
}
```

I was wondering if anyone has seen anything like this and can explain to me what this if statement is.

Comment: It might be something that is processed in some build process before the CSS is deployed?

Comment: Sorry, just read the question properly, d'oh rtfq!  It is a liquid if statement so that if the settings isn't equal to no_password_bg then it changes the font colour of the anchor to white - your css file will have a `.liquid` extension on it if that works properly

Comment: It does, all the shopify files have .liquid is that a file type specific to shopify?  Now I need to do research on .liquid haha. I've only ever seen it in shopify.

Comment: It's shopify's own language, not too bad but not great either.  They have a pretty good [documentation centre](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid) though so it's usually pretty easy to find out how to do stuff

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `{% if %}` from Liquid template engine, probably this code is not in a CSS file and is raw on a view file.

You have more information on the documentation here:

https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/basics

Comment: This is the file name where I found the code. stylesheet.css.liquid

Comment: As @Pete said, they have his own language is not pure CSS, you can check the docs :)

Answer (score 0):

This statement is related to your theme settings.

Theme settings are options defined by theme dev in «schema_settings.json» file.

Eventually this statement shouldn't work in a .css.liquid file which only supports and renders Liquid strings.

For example {{ mystring }} works.
But {% if some_condition %}do_sthg{% endif %} shouldn't.

HTH

Answer (score -1):

This is probably a server side notation that slipped into the client.
Since it's [Shopify](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_django_app) - I would assume they use [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) - a web development platform written in python:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#if

Comment: you assume wrong - [this is shopify](https://www.shopify.co.uk/) - it's an ecommerce platform you pay for and not available to download via github

Comment: @Pete, what makes you say that?

Comment: You're right, just went over some of their job openings. They mostly dwell around RoR/mySQL and such.